# After upgrade from OG6 to OG7 directly to ver. 2.x: Is there any possibility to use OG migrate (available only in OG 1.5)?

Tags: organic-groups, migrations

I´ve realised that OG Migrate is only in 7.x-1.5 but NOT in OG 2.x.

I´ve accidentally updated my site from D6 to D7 directely to OG 2.x.

Is there anything I could do to use OG migrate?

Comment: I made the same mistake. Had to roll back to a backup and start again using OG 7.1

Comment: Can´t believe there isn´t any other way... what a pity

Answer (score 0):

For OG 7.x-2.2, the migrate functionality is now coming with the OG module itself. No additional module is needed. Documentation can be found here:

[Migrate: Contributed module support: Organic Groups](https://drupal.org/node/2023273)

Which means the functionality is no longer in [migrate_og](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_og) (where it was for OG 6.x-1.x) and also no longer in [migrate_extras](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_extras) (where it was, I think, for OG 7.x-1.x).